# Showing that a morphism is unique

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma, representable-functor

Suppose we have two representables $H_A, H_{A'}: \mathscr A\to \mathbf {Set}$ and a natural transformation $H_A\to H_{A'}$ with components $\alpha_B:H_A(B)\to H_{A'}(B)$. It can be shown that each $\alpha_B(u)=f\circ u$ for some $f:A\to A'$. How to show that this $f$ is unique?

Suppose $f\circ u=g\circ u$. The natural first thought is to cancel $u$, but it's not necessarily an epimorphism, so there must be some more complicated argument that I can't think of.

Comment: Hint: what is $\alpha_B(id)?$

Comment: @КряжевАрсений Do you mean $\alpha_A(id_A)$? Well, it's $f$, but I'm not sure how this helps. Your hint reminds me of the Yoneda lemma, during the proof of which it's proved that a natural transformation $H_A\to X$ is determined by its value at $1_A$ but I was thinking of a direct (and maybe simpler?) proof in this particular case.

Comment: Does it equal $f$ or does it equal $g$?

Comment: Oh, I see, if $\alpha_B(u)=f\circ u$ and $\alpha_B(u)=g\circ u$ for all $u$, then taking $u=id_A$ shows that $f=g$.